# BUILD FAILED, NullPointerException from "sencha app build native"

Tags: android, extjs, cordova, sencha-touch

I'm trying to get my Sencha App to work on Android devices.

I'm running;

- Windows 8
- Sencha Architect 3
- Sencha Touch 2.3.1
- Sencha Cmd 4.0.2.67
- Cordova 3.4.0-0.1.3
- Phonegap 3.4.0-0.19.7

I had an app working in my local browser when I ran the localhost called DemoApp.  I went into my terminal into the app directory and ran `cordova platform add android` and it was successful.  But when I run `sencha app build native` I get the following error.

```
[ERR] BUILD FAILED
[ERR] java.lang.NullPointerException
[ERR] 
[ERR] The error occurred while executing this line: 
[ERR] C:\Projects\DemoApp\.sencha\app\build-impl.xml:291: 
The following error occurred while executing this line:
C:\Projects\DemoApp\.sencha\app\resources-impl.xml:7: 
java.lang.NullPointerException
```

I honestly have no clue what to do here.  I've Google'd the problem and all i can find is Unanswered questions in the Sencha Forums.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out.

The app I was trying to put on mobile devices was generated by `Sencha Architect` using the `ExtJS` framework, not the `Sencha-Touch` framework.  When I made a simple `Sencha-Touch` app and followed these steps it worked and I was able to put it on my mobile device.

```
C:\Projects\DemoApp> sencha phonegap init
C:\Projects\DemoApp> cd phonegap
C:\Projects\DemoApp\phonegap> cordova platform add android
C:\Projects\DemoApp\phonegap> cd ..
C:\Projects\DemoApp> sencha app build native
```

After this you should be able to run the app on your emulater/device however you would do so.

Comment: which steps do you refer?

Comment: @FranciscoCorrales I was referring to the steps that were failing in my original post.  I have added ALL the steps to my answer with proper format for clarity.

Answer (score -1):

I sloved my problem by using reinstal jdk 8.0